# limit involving arcsin

Tags: calculus

How can we evaluate the following limit if it exists

$\lim_{x \to -3} \arcsin{(\dfrac{x+3}{x^2+4x+3})}$

I get stuck because when I factorize our problem is simplified to

$\lim_{x \to -3} \arcsin{(\dfrac{1}{x+1})}=\lim_{x \to -3} \arcsin{(-\dfrac{1}{2})}$

Then how to progress?  $\arcsin (-\dfrac{1}{2})$ takes more than one value. How can I decide  what is the value of the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function normally speaking should return only one value. In case of arcsin, the default range is from $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. In this case $\arcsin(-1/2)= -\pi/6$.